# Will I need DLC to play TW: Warhammer 1 factions in TW: Warhammer 2?

Tags: warhammer-total-war, warhammer-ii-total-war

From what I understand I'm able to play races from TW: W1 in TW: W2 (Wood Elves/Empire/Bretonia/Dwarfs/..) only if I have TW: W1. Does this apply to DLCs as well? I.e. can I play Beastman if and only if I have 'Call of Beastman'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

To be able to play a race in the Mortal Empires campaign or multiplayer in WH2, you need to own the respective WH1 DLC.